# HTML 5 form validation using checkValidity doesn't show default red/orange border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Using html 5 form validation I would like to validate my forms which we retreive using ajax.

When I validate my form (using `.checkValidity()`) the default invalid red/orange border using firefox/chrome does not show.

When I click an `input[type="submit"]` it does show this red border.

See this jsfiddle for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jyaHZ/

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I do think that you still have to do the CSS styling yourself. All that HTML5 adds here is a `:invalid` and `:valid` pseudoclass that you can use like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/jyaHZ/4/)**.

More info on HTML5 form validation at **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation_API)**

**EDIT**:

Apparently I can correct myself as it states **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3a-moz-ui-invalid)** that:

> By default, Gecko applies a style that creates a red "glow" (using the
>   box-shadow property) around items with that have this pseudo-class
>   applied. See the :invalid pseudo-class for an example that shows how
>   to override the default style.

Although I - too - cannot see this behavior in Firefox (neither Chrome)

Comment: @kommradHomer No, Chrome is using Webkit, I was just too lazy to look up the wekbit specs.....

Comment: perhaps i've confused things terribly. V8 is the java script engine http://code.google.com/p/v8/

Comment: Thank you, apperantly this isn't possible (yet) triggering this in javascript. I'll just hook into the submit event instead.

Comment: @jeffreydev The weird thing is that the pseudoclass is constantly updated with the correct value as you can just use it in the stylesheets without any problems. My guess would be that the docs just left out the part where it says *applies after first submit*